# Euler's Front 9

Tags: code-golf, math

[image]

**[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/)** is another fun programming challenge site to compete (well, play) on.  Early problems start off gently, but then explode in difficulty beyond the first hundred or so. The first few problems have some commonality between finding primes, multiples, and factors, so there could be some interesting code micro-reuse opportunities to toy with.

So, **write a program that solves, using no *a priori* knowledge, any of the first 9 [problems](http://projecteuler.net/problems).**

1. The problem is selected by the user, ASCII '1' through '9', inclusive, via an argument when calling or standard input while running.  (You can compute all the answers, but only show one.)
2. The correct answer must be printed on a new line, in base 10, using ASCII.
3. Programs should execute in less than a minute (PE suggestion).
4. By "no *a priori* knowledge", I mean *your code* must derive the answer without external resources<sup>‡</sup>.  A program like this would be considered invalid (otherwise correct though, assuming I didn't make a typo):

   ```
   print[233168,4613732,6857,906609,232792560,25164150,104743,40824,31875000][input()-1]
   ```

   <sup>‡</sup>for problem #8 (involves a 1000-digit number), you may read the number from an external file, just specify how it's stored (e.g. binary, text, header, imported module) and/or include it in your answer post (does not count towards the length of the main program).
5. Score is by bytes.
6. Fifteen Unicorn Points™ awarded to the byte-count leader after 2 weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Python, 505

```
import f
A,B,C,D=map(range,[22,1000,101,500])
R=reduce
M=int.__mul__
a=x=0
b=1
n=2
p=[]
while b<=4e6:a,b=b,a+b;x+=b*(b%2<1)
while len(p)<=1e4:p+=[n]*all(n%i for i in p);n+=1
q=y=R(M,p[:8])
while any(y%(i+1)for i in A):y+=q
print[
    sum(i for i in B if i%3*(i%5)<1),
    x,
    max(i for i in p if 600851475143%i<1),
    max(a*b for a in B for b in B if`a*b`==`a*b`[::-1]),
    y,
    sum(C)**2-sum(i**2for i in C),
    p[-1],
    max(R(M,map(int,f.s[i:i+5]))for i in B),
    [a*b*(1000-a-b)for a in D for b in D if(a+b)*1e3==5e5+a*b][0]
][input()-1]
```

Whitespace is added to the last line for readability. The 1000-digit number is imported from a module named `f.py` containing the line:

```
s="7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
```

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript

**Solution: 1785 chars**

execute code with nodeJS

note on problem 7 : algorithm is ok, but it take a moment ! If someone has a more efficient solution...

```
z=process.argv[2]
y=console.log
if(z==1){b=0;for(i=1e3;i--;)if(i%3<1||i%5<1)b+=i;y(b)}
if(z==2){d=e=1;f=0;while(e<=4e6)g=d+e,d=e,e=g,f+=e%2<1?e:0;y(f)}
if(z==3){e=Math.sqrt(d=600851475143)|0+1;f=2;while(f<e){g=d/f;if(g==(g|0))h=f,d=g;f+=f==2?1:2}y(h)}
if(z==4){for(a=b=100,c=0;a+b<1998;){d=a++*b;if(d==(""+d).split("").reverse().join("")&&d>c)c=d;if(a>999)a=b+1,b++}y(c)}
if(z==5){for(a=c=1;c;){for(b=20;b>1;)a%b>0?b=0:b--;b==1?c=0:a++}y(a)}
if(z==6){for(a=100,b=Math.pow(a*(a+1)/2,2),d=a+1;d--;)b-=d*d;y(b)}
if(z==7){for(a=3,c=d=0;c<1e4;){for(b=a;b>2;){b=b>3?b-2:2;if(a%b<1)b=0}if(b>0)c++,d=a;a=a+2}y(d)}
if(z==8){a="7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";for(e=0,b=996;b--;){d=eval(a.substr(b,5).split("").join("*"));if(d>e)e=d};y(e)}
if(z==9){for(a=b=0;(c=a+b+Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b))!=1e3;)if(++a==500)a=0,b++;y(a,b,c-b-a)}
```

**problem 1: 39 chars**

```
b=0;for(i=1e3;i--;)if(i%3<1||i%5<1)b+=i
```

**problem 2: 49 chars**

```
d=e=1;f=0;while(e<=4e6)g=d+e,d=e,e=g,f+=e%2<1?e:0
```

**problem 3: 85 chars**

```
e=Math.sqrt(d=600851475143)|0+1;f=2;while(f<e){g=d/f;if(g==(g|0))h=f,d=g;f+=f==2?1:2}
```

**problem 4: 105 chars**

```
for(a=b=100,c=0;a+b<1998;){d=a++*b;if(d==(""+d).split("").reverse().join("")&&d>c)c=d;if(a>999)a=b+1,b++}
```

**problem 5: 55 chars**

```
for(a=c=1;c;){for(b=20;b>1;)a%b>0?b=0:b--;b==1?c=0:a++}
```

**problem 6: 51 chars**

```
for(a=100,b=Math.pow(a*(a+1)/2,2),d=a+1;d--;)b-=d*d
```

**problem 7: 82 chars**

```
for(a=3,c=d=0;c<1e4;){for(b=a;b>2;){b=b>3?b-2:2;if(a%b<1)b=0}if(b>0)c++,d=a;a=a+2}
```

**problem 8: 1078 chars ^_^**

```
a="7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
for(e=0,b=996;b--;){d=eval(a.substr(b,5).split("").join("*"));if(d>e)e=d}
```

**problem 9: 58 chars**

```
for(a=b=0;a+b+Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b)!=1e3;)if(++a==500)a=0,b++
```

Comment: `if(i%3<1||i%5<1)a+=i` is shorter ! :)

Comment: Shorter problem 3: `e=Math.sqrt(d=600851475143)|0+1;f=2;while(f<e){g=d/f;if(g==g|0)h=f,d=g;f+=f==2?1:2}`

Comment: Shorter problem 4: `for(a=b=100,c=0;a+b<1998;){d=a++*b;if(d==(""+d).split("").reverse().join("")&&d>c)c=d;if(a>999)a=b+1,b++}`

Comment: @Florent : problem 3 `g==g|0` doesn't work `g|0` must be between parenthesis

Comment: I tried without it and worked as expected!

Comment: @Florent : the solution is in variable `h`, not the value returned by the script

Comment: problem 6 shorter : `for(a=100,b=Math.pow(a*(a+1)/2,2),d=a+1;d--;)b-=d*d`

Comment: Thx very much, Michael !

Comment: Does JS have some facility to import from another file to spare you 1kB of number?

Comment: NodeJS can load easily a file but I consider these numbers as a part of problem !

Answer (score 1):

#### R 684 characters

```
f=function(N){r=rowSums;p=function(x,y)r(!outer(x,y,`%%`));S=sum;x=c(1,1);n=600851475143;a=900:999;b=20;c=1:100;m=2:sqrt(n);M=m[!n%%m];A=a%o%a;d=3;P=2;z=1:1e3;Z=expand.grid(z,z);Y=cbind(Z,sqrt(r(Z^2)));W=gsub("\n","",xpathApply(htmlParse("http://projecteuler.net/problem=8"),"//p",xmlValue)[[2]]);switch(N,S(which(p(1:999,c(3,5))>0)),{while(tail(x,1)<4e6)x=c(x,S(tail(x,2)));S(x[!x%%2])},max(M[p(M,M)<2]),max(A[sapply(strsplit(c(A,""),""),function(x)all(x==rev(x)))],na.rm=T),{while(any(b%%1:20>0))b=b+20;b},S(c)^2-S(c^2),{while(P<=1e4){d=d+2;if(sum(!d%%2:d)<2)P=P+1};d},max(sapply(5:nchar(W),function(i)prod(as.integer(strsplit(substr(W,i-4,i),"")[[1]])))),prod(Y[r(Y)==1000,][1,]))}
```

Indented:

```r
f=function(N){
    r=rowSums
    p=function(x,y)r(!outer(x,y,`%%`))
    S=sum
    x=c(1,1)
    n=600851475143
    a=900:999
    b=20
    c=1:100
    m=2:sqrt(n)
    M=m[!n%%m]
    A=a%o%a
    d=3
    P=2
    z=1:1e3
    Z=expand.grid(z,z)
    Y=cbind(Z,sqrt(r(Z^2)))
    W=gsub("\n","",xpathApply(htmlParse("http://projecteuler.net/problem=8"),"//p",xmlValue)[[2]])
    switch(N,S(which(p(1:999,c(3,5))>0)),
             {while(tail(x,1)<4e6)x=c(x,S(tail(x,2)));S(x[!x%%2])},
             max(M[p(M,M)<2]),
             max(A[sapply(strsplit(c(A,""),""),function(x)all(x==rev(x)))],na.rm=T),
             {while(any(b%%1:20>0))b=b+20;b},
             S(c)^2-S(c^2),
             {while(P<=1e4){d=d+2;if(sum(!d%%2:d)<2)P=P+1};d},
             max(sapply(5:nchar(W),function(i)prod(as.integer(strsplit(substr(W,i-4,i),"")[[1]])))),
             prod(Y[r(Y)==1000,][1,]))
    }
```

Usage:

```
> f(1)
[1] 233168
> f(2)
[1] 4613732
> f(3)
[1] 6857
> f(4)
[1] 906609
> f(5)
[1] 232792560
> f(6)
[1] 25164150
> f(7)
[1] 104743
> f(8)
[1] 40824
> f(9)
[1] 31875000
```

Separately:

**1: 48 chars** `` sum(which(rowSums(!outer(1:999,c(3,5),`%%`))>0)) ``

**2: 64 chars** `x=c(1,1);while(tail(x,1)<4e6)x=c(x,sum(tail(x,2)));sum(x[!x%%2])`

**3: 73 chars** `` n=600851475143;m=2:sqrt(n);M=m[!n%%m];max(M[rowSums(!outer(M,M,`%%`))<2]) ``

**4: 88 chars** `a=900:999;b=a%o%a;max(b[sapply(strsplit(c(b,""),""),function(x)all(x==rev(x)))],na.rm=T)`

**5: 34 chars** `a=20;while(any(a%%1:20>0))a=a+20;a`

**6: 25 chars** `a=1:100;sum(a)^2-sum(a^2)`

**7: 54 chars** `d=3;P=2;while(P<=1e4){d=d+2;if(sum(!d%%2:d)<2)P=P+1};d`

**8: 181 chars**

First line reads the number from the project euler website, second line actualy perform the computation.

```
W=gsub("\n","",xpathApply(htmlParse("http://projecteuler.net/problem=8"),"//p",xmlValue)[[2]])
max(sapply(5:nchar(W),function(i)prod(as.integer(strsplit(substr(W,i-4,i),"")[[1]]))))
```

**9: 87 chars** `z=1:1e3;Z=expand.grid(z,z);Y=cbind(Z,sqrt(rowSums(Z^2)));prod(Y[rowSums(Y)==1000,][1,])`

Comment: As of now, `f(7)` takes 2 mins to compute so it doesn't really comply to the execution time constraint. I'll try to work on that. (`f(5)` takes 48s on my machine)

Answer (score 1):

### J <s>245</s> <s>236</s> 232

```
load'n'
echo".>(<:".1!:1]1){<;._1'!+/I.+./0=5 3|,:~i.1e3!+/}:(],4&*@:{:+_2&{)^:(4e6>{:)^:_]0 2!{:q:600851475143!>./(#~(-:|.)@":"0),/*/~i.1e3!*./>:i.20!(([:*:+/)-[:+/*:)i.101!p:1e4!>./5*/\"."0 n!x:*/{.(#~1e3=+/"1)(+.,|)"0,j./~i.500'
```

n is a file containing the following:

```
n=:'7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450'
```

Answer (score 0):

### TI-BASIC (Work in Progress)

*For your TI-83 or TI-84 calculator*

Main program, **15 bytes**:

```
Input X:OpenLib(1):X:ExecLib:Disp Ans
```

Library 1 (**4 bytes**) **does** count toward the total number of bytes:

```
L1(Ans
```

Then, we have List #1:

```
work in progress
```